# Filters to find intersection of two arrays in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native, filter

I'd like to filter an array of objects.
The array is a list of sport classes, and the objects are the classes.

It looks like this :

```
const list = [{category: "yoga", level: "beginner", duration: "15 minutes"}]
```

I have to apply filter so the user can choose between category (yoga, pilates...) level (beginner, advanced..).

I need to find the intersection of the filter, meaning if "yoga" and "beginner" are selected, I'd like to return only *beginner yoga* classes.

User can turn true/false the variables beginnnerFilter etc.. and the variables cardio/yoga etc...
So if the yoga filter is true, yogaFilter = "yoga". If false, yogaFilter = ""

Example:

```
function filterIntersect() {
  let filteredListCategory = [];
  let filteredListLevel = [];

  
  for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i].category.toLowerCase() === cardio) {
       filteredListCategory.push(list[i])
   } else if (list[i].category.toLowerCase() === yoga) {
       filteredListCategory.push(list[i])
   } else if (list[i].category.toLowerCase() === boxing) {
       filteredListCategory.push(list[i])
   } else if (list[i].category.toLowerCase() === dance) {
       filteredListCategory.push(list[i])
   } else if (list[i].category.toLowerCase() === pilates) {
       filteredListCategory.push(list[i])
   } else if (list[i].category.toLowerCase() === stretching) {
       filteredListCategory.push(list[i])
   } 
  }

  if (allFilterCategory === true) {
       filteredListCategory = [...list];
   }

  for(let k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {
    if (list[k].level.toLowerCase() === beginnerFilter) {
       filteredListLevel.push(list[k])
   } else if (list[k].level.toLowerCase() === intermediateFilter) {
       filteredListLevel.push(list[k])
   } else if (list[k].level.toLowerCase() === advancedFilter) {
       filteredListLevel.push(list[k])
   }
  } 

  if (allFilterLevel === true) {
       filteredListLevel = [...list];
   }

let finalList = filteredListCategory.filter(item=> filteredListLevel.includes(item));

return finalList.length === 0 ? list : finalList;
}
```

I manage to return a filtered array but it doesn't work as expected. Sometimes the filters do not apply and I have the full list instead of the filtered list.
I'm not sure the for loop is appropriate here? I also tried using new Set but was not working either. Big thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.filter` and `.some` method of arrays instead of `if`-statements and `for`-loops. E.g.

```js
  const categoryChoices = [
    { category: "yoga", checked: false },
    { category: "meditation", checked: true },
    { category: "pilates", checked: false },
    { category: "cardio", checked: true },
  ];

  const levelsChoices = [
    { level: "beginner", checked: true },
    { level: "intermediate", checked: true },
    { level: "advanced", checked: false },
  ];

  const data = [
    { category: "yoga", level: "beginner", duration: '30 minutes' },
    { category: "yoga", level: "intermediate", duration: '60 minutes' },
    { category: "yoga", level: "advanced", duration: '90 minutes' },
    { category: "meditation", level: "beginner", duration: '30 minutes' },
    { category: "meditation", level: "intermediate", duration: '60 minutes' },
    { category: "meditation", level: "advanced", duration: '90 minutes' },
    { category: "pilates", level: "beginner", duration: '30 minutes' },
    { category: "pilates", level: "intermediate", duration: '60 minutes' },
    { category: "pilates", level: "advanced", duration: '90 minutes' },
    { category: "cardio", level: "beginner", duration: '30 minutes' },
    { category: "cardio", level: "intermediate", duration: '60 minutes' },
    { category: "cardio", level: "advanced", duration: '90 minutes' },
  ];

  const checkedCategories = categoryChoices
    .filter((c) => c.checked)
    .map((c) => c.category);
  const checkedLevels = levelsChoices
    .filter((l) => l.checked)
    .map((l) => l.level);

  const filteredData = data.filter(
    ({ category, level }) =>
      checkedCategories.some((c) => c === category) &&
      checkedLevels.some((l) => l === level)
  );

  console.log(filteredData);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @user2037443, it words like a charm. 
I can even add more filters and filter by coach for instance.

I added an if statement in case the "all" filter is selected to return the whole array :

`if (checkedLevels.length === 0) {checkedLevels = levelsChoices.map((c) => c.level);}`